# How to produce a single plot with geom_pointranges over geom_ribbon? (Basically to show the data points and their standard deviations)

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I have here are two graphs "PlotA" and "PlotB", however I want a combined graph with geom_pointranges showing points, geom_line showing the line and geom_ribbon showing the standard deviation.

```
water <- c(35,40,42,46,48,50)
depth <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
sd <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10)
dataA <- data.frame(depth, water, sd)

from <- c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)
to <- c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5)
depth1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
water1 <- c(40,32,50,55,62,30)
dataB <- data.frame(from,to,depth1, water1)

# Load necessary packages

require(ggplot2)

# Plotting Started

#PlotA
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x = water, y = depth), na.rm=T) +
geom_path(size=0.4, color="black")+
geom_pointrange(data=dataB, aes(water1, depth1, ymin=from, ymax=to),      size=0.1, color='black') +
scale_y_reverse(lim = c(10,0), breaks = seq(0,10,1)) +
theme_bw(12) +
scale_x_continuous(lim =c(0,100), breaks = seq(0,100,20))

#PlotB
ggplot() + geom_ribbon(data=dataA, aes(x=depth, y=water, ymin = water - sd,   ymax = water + sd), alpha=0.3, fill='grey12') + coord_flip() + 
scale_x_reverse(lim = c(10,0), breaks = seq(0,10,1)) + theme_bw(12) +
scale_y_continuous(lim =c(0,100), breaks = seq(0,100,20))
```

Comment: please update your question as it's unclear what final result are you expecting

Comment: Hi there, I just want a single graph with PlotA and PlotB combined one over another.

Comment: The title is updated. I hope it is a little clear now. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't help, my answer had points over ribbon...

Comment: It looks like zoo, ggvis, gridExtra, dplyr, and cowplot are not used in your question - I would suggest removing them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coord_flip` is difficult to use well in the middle of a plot. I strongly recommend debugging plots without it and then adding it as the last step.

I think this is what you're looking for. If not, please describe your desired result in more detail.

```
ggplot(data = dataA, aes(x = depth, y = water)) +
    geom_ribbon(
        data = dataA,
        aes(
            x = depth,
            ymin = water - sd,
            ymax = water + sd
        ),
        alpha = 0.3,
        fill = 'grey12'
    ) +
    geom_path(size = 0.4, color = "black") +
    geom_point(
        data = dataB,
        aes(x = depth1, y = water1),
        size = 0.1,
        color = 'black'
    ) +
    geom_errorbarh(
        data = dataB,
        aes(
            x = depth1,
            xmin = from,
            xmax = to,
            y = water1
        ),
        size = 0.1,
        height = 0
    ) +
    theme_bw(12) +
    scale_x_reverse(lim = c(10, 0), breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(lim = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: This is such a magic. Works 100% fine. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much Gregor. That was absolutely fantastic.